# Is this HashMap usage thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a static HashMap which will cache objects identifed by unique integers; it will be accessed from multiple threads. I will have multiple instances of the type `HashmapUser` running in different threads, each of which will want to utilize the same HashMap (which is why it's static).

Generally, the `HashmapUsers` will be retrieving from the HashMap. Though if it is empty, it needs to be populated from a Database. Also, in some cases the HashMap will be cleared because it needs the data has change and it needs to be repopulated.

So, I just make all interactions with the Map syncrhonized. But I'm not positive that this is safe, smart, or that it works for a static variable.

Is the below implementation of this thread safe? Any suggestions to simplify or otherwise improve it?

```
public class HashmapUser {

  private static HashMap<Integer, AType> theMap = new HashSet<>();

  public HashmapUser() {
    //....
  }

  public void performTask(boolean needsRefresh, Integer id) {
    //....

    AType x = getAtype(needsRefresh, id);

    //....
  }

  private synchronized AType getAtype(boolean needsRefresh, Integer id) {
    if (needsRefresh) {
      theMap.clear();
    }

    if (theMap.size() == 0) {
      // populate the set
    }

    return theMap.get(id);
  }
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason you're not using `ConcurrentHashMap`, the thread-safe version of `HashMap`?

Comment: well, my concurrency issues result from cases like: multiple threads think the hashmap is empty and try to populate it at the same time, one thread thinks the hashmap is populated but by the time it tries to retrieve from it another thread has cleared it. A ConcurrentHashMap doesn't solve these issues. (I think?)

Comment: Your synchronized is useless, since you have many instances of HashmapUser. Thread A will obtain the lock on user1, while thread B obtains the lock on user2, and both will thus access the map concurrently. You need a single object, shared by all the users, and chich is the only one to access the map. And the methods of this object are the ones that must be synchronized.

Comment: Why don't you do the initialisation as you need it - each client thread needs something, looks up the cache, if the resource is not there - fetches it from the db and then puts it in the cache. Or you could just prefetch all the data and cache it before any clients hit it.

Comment: I ab11 makes a good point, @Powerlord: using `ConcurrentHashMap` doesn't necessarily make the entire class thread-safe -- if only it were that simple -- that said, it's often a good start.

Comment: @DavidS Yeah, I realized that after noting that clear and repopulate were separate actions.

Comment: Instead of making `theMap` static, you could make it an instance variable, and then have the default constructor set it to point to a singleton `HashMap`.  Why?  Because then you could make a second constructor that lets the caller pass in a given `HashMap`.  Why?  Because then your unit tests for the `HashmapUser` class could use the second constructor to _inject_ test doubles (stubs and mocks) for the `HashMap`.  You are unit testing, right?  `static` is the enemy of testing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is, it is definitely not thread-safe. Each instance of `HashmapUsers` will use a different lock (`this`), which does nothing useful. You have to synchronise on the same object, such as the HashMap itself.

Change `getAtype` to:

```
private AType getAtype(boolean needsRefresh, Integer id) {
    synchronized(theMap) {
        if (needsRefresh) {
          theMap.clear();
        }

        if (theMap.size() == 0) {
          // populate the set
        }

        return theMap.get(id);
    }
  }
```

Edit:
Note that you can synchronize on any object, provided that all instances use the same object for synchronization. You could synchronize on `HashmapUsers.class`, which also allows for other objects to lock access to the map (though it is typically best practice to use a private lock).

Because of this, simply making your `getAtype` method static would work, since the implied lock would now be `HashMapUsers.class` instead of `this`. However, this exposes your lock, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: Still useless, if there are multiple instances of HashmapUser

Comment: @Daniel How so? The lock is the HashMap itself, so only one instance can enter the `synchronized` region at a time.

Comment: this makes sense. there is only one (static) map instance, so if I synchronize on that everything should be safe. given this, is there any advantage to using ConcurrentHashmap or some other thread safe collection?

Comment: @ab11 `ConcurrentHashMap` won't help because there's no single method call for "clear, populate, and get". Using `Collections.synchronizedMap` won't help either, for the same reason - you will need a full `synchronized` block to make the whole operation atomic.

Comment: Note that there is the `merge` method in ConcurrentHashMap in Java 8, which works for individual keys (the remapping function would either use the existing value, or reload from the database, depending on the value of your `refresh` parameter), but this wouldn't be able to refresh the entire map, only the single key you are looking at, which means you would hit the database a lot more.

Comment: @Meindratheal So, it would probably be fair to say that `ConcurrentHashMap` would just add unnecessary overhead and making the operation atomic by synchronizing on the single `HashMap` instance is a good solution?

Answer (score 1):

No, this won't work at all.

If you don't specify lock object, e.g. declare method `synchronized`, the implicit lock will be instance. Unless the method is static then the lock will be class. Since there are multiple instances, there are also multiple locks, which i doubt is desired.

What you should do is create another class which is the only class with the access to `HashMap`.

Clients of `HashMap`, such as the `HashMapUser` must not even be aware that there is synchronization in place. Instead, thread safety should be assured by the proper class wrapping the `HashMap` hiding the synchronization from the clients.

This lets you easily add additional clients to the `HashMap` since synchronization is hidden from them, otherwise you would have to add some kind of synchronization between the different client types too.

Comment: What is the point of adding the extra class?  The `HashmapUser` class already _is_ the only class that knows about `theMap`.

Comment: Single responsbility principle. Without knowing your full implementation it is hard to say how much and is it violated. The way i see it, there should be Cache (Hash Map) and Users. It might be that just the naming is off a bit, but HashMapUser implies business logic and cache-database sync in a single class.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you go with either `ConcurrentHashMap` or `SynchronizedMap`.
More info here: http://crunchify.com/hashmap-vs-concurrenthashmap-vs-synchronizedmap-how-a-hashmap-can-be-synchronized-in-java/

`ConcurrentHashMap` is more suitable for high - concurrency scenarios. This implementation doesn't synchronize on the whole object, but rather does that in an optimised way, so different threads, accessing different keys can do that simultaneously.

`SynchronizerMap` is simpler and does synchronization on the object level - the access to the instance is serial.

I think you need performance, so I think you should probably go with `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: `SynchronizerMap` will not work here.  While it guarantees the map itself won't be damaged by concurrent access, it doesn't guarantee invariants between individual accesses.  It's possible, for instance, for multiple threads to see `theMap.size() == 0` then simultaneously populate it.

Comment: Neither `ConcurrentHashMap` nor `SynchronizedMap` is a magic wand that will make a program thread safe.  Look at the OP's `HashmapUser` class:  The synchronized methods do more than just one operation each.  The `getAType(...)` looks as if it needs to synchronize a _sequence_ of operations.  Can't tell about the other methods:  It depends on what the `...` stands for.